# What information was on the the "Reflections: A Game of Dueling Samurai" character sheet?

Tags: character-sheets, reflections-rpg

[*Reflections: A Game of Dueling Samurai*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/202679/Reflections-A-Game-of-Dueling-Samurai) plays in multiple rounds of conversations between two players. During each of those rounds, each player chooses a goal they're trying to get out of the scene. The specific goals for each round were recorded on the character sheets, but not in the book that I can find.

When I did some digging, I was pointed to [a link that should have had the character sheets](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6gyyiuiayr0n1w/reflections_character-sheet.pdf?dl=0), but is now dead.

Ultimately what I'm looking for: What information not included in the rulebooks was recorded on the character sheets for this game?

Comment: If you search for "Reflections RPG character sheet" on Google Image Search, the first result is a tweet with a photo of a character sheet that's been torn in half (both halves are in the photo). The goals you're talking about seem to be listed on the sheet, and are still very readable despite the tear. I'm not really familiar with the RPG, but you could probably post a good self-answer to your own question based on that image. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** I messaged user [Dicktremain](https://www.reddit.com/u/Dicktremain) on Reddit (Jim McClure, owner of Third Act Publishing) to ask for the Character Sheet, and was provided with [this Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/luzy5qp8nrd3tl6/reflections_character-sheet.pdf?dl=0).

---

Based on [this image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DriEAoXWkAAW5OY?format=jpg&name=large) (from [this November 8, 2018 tweet by @pixelscapes](https://twitter.com/pixelscapes/status/1060742866996203520)), here is the information on the Reflections Character Sheet:

| Player | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It was a time of _________ |
| 2 | We stand upon _________ |
| 1 | I remember when you were _________ |
| 2 | This feud started when _________ |
| 1 | My name is _________ I am a _________ and I cannot allow your actions to go unchallenged |
| 2 | My name is _________ I am a _________ and I cannot allow your actions to go unchallenged |

### Reflections

|  | The time we were friends |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Die | Choose your own objective _________ |
| 2 Dice | Get your rival to agree to do something in the future |
| 3 Dice | Get your rival to give you a personal item |
| 4 Dice | Get your rival to reveal their greatest personal weakness |

|  | The time you crossed the line |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Die | Choose your own objective _________ |
| 2 Dice | Get your rival to do something for selfish reasons |
| 3 Dice | Get your rival to ignore their honor or duties |
| 4 Dice | Get your rival to draw blood from another person |

|  | The time you failed me |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Die | Choose your own objective _________ |
| 2 Dice | Get your rival to speak out against you |
| 3 Dice | Get your rival to walk out of an important event |
| 4 Dice | Get your rival to break a promise made earlier |

|  | The time we strived for peace |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Die | Choose your own objective _________ |
| 2 Dice | Get your rival to say something admirable about you |
| 3 Dice | Get your rival to admit something they did wrong |
| 4 Dice | Get your rival to ask you for help |

|  | The time it came to blood |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Die | Choose your own objective _________ |
| 2 Dice | Take something important away from your rival |
| 3 Dice | Get your rival to renounce something they once believed in |
| 4 Dice | Get your rival to commit a true act of evil |

Then at the very bottom of the sheet are two rows, one labeled Dice and one labeled Hatred. Each has 20 blank circles after the label.

---

Note: based on [this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/7fgcdz/character_sheet_for_reflections_a_game_of_dueling/dqbpwbb?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and other sources on the web, this form *was* publicly available, though it is no longer.